# understanding recurrence relation between two measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

[image]

Hi, Could anyone explain to me how he wrote $(3.3)$ to $(3.4)$, in particular, why double integration? I am convinced with $(3.3)$ and another thing, I do not quite understand the role of $p(x,t)$.

Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $p$ is the conditional density of $t_n$ given $x_n$ (with respect to Lebesgue measure on $[0, T]$).
That is, equation (3.2) implies that
$$
\Pr(t_n \in \mathcal{T} \mid x_n)
= \int_{\mathcal{T}} p(x_n, u) \, du
$$
for any Borel set $\mathcal{T} \subseteq [0, T]$.

It follows from some "usual" measure-theoretic arguments that
$$
\tag{1}
E[g(x_n, t_n) \mid x_n]
= \int_0^T g(x_n, u) p(x_n, u) \, du
$$
for any sufficiently nice (e.g., bounded and measurable) function $g : X \times [0, T] \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now we can verify equation (3.4):
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[h(x_{n+1})]
&= E[h(S(x_n, t_n))] \\
&= E[E[h(S(x_n, t_n)) \mid x_n]] &&\text{double expectation theorem}\\
&= E\left[\int_0^T h(S(x_n, u)) p(x_n, u) \, du\right] &&\text{using (1) with $g(x, t)=h(S(x, t))$}
\\&= \int_X \left[\int_0^T h(S(x, t)) p(x, t) \, dt\right] \, \mu_n(dx)
&&\text{since $\mu_n$ is the distribution of $x_n$}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.